# How To Add A Caption To A GridView Cell

Tags: java, android, image, gridview, text

Hi All I am Using a GridView Tool From The Android To Display The Image As A menu

I am Using this Code in A class I Name It `ImageAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter`

[image: Screenshot Of The Gridview With Images Without Text]

I've Use This Code Bellow

```
package com.example.gridviewtest;

import com.example.gridviewtest.R;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = 
        {
            R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8, R.drawable.pic9
        };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I try to use a

```
imageView.setText("Something");
```

but it doesn't Works With Me 
the require is to add a caption under a picture in a cell

Can You Help Me On This ...

Best Regards ...

Comment: @Metalhead1247 LoL :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a custom adapter (as for a listView):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
     Activity context;   
     ArrayList<Integer> objects;

     public CustomAdapter(Activity context,  ArrayList<Integer> objects) {
      super(context, R.layout.row, objects);
      this.context = context;
      this.objects = objects;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);


      } 

      ImageView i = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
      i.setBackgroundResource(objects.get(position));

      TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      t.setText("title");

      return convertView;

     }

    }
```

And of course you will set this it as an adapter for the gridView.

**EDIT:** Of course instead of `ArrayAdapter<Integer>` you could be extending `ArrayAdapter<YourHolder>`.

```
class YourHolder {
  public int ID;
  public String title;
}
```

**EDIT 2: Adding a functional piece of code.**

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#600000ff"     
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

grid_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#6000ff00"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="label"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </FrameLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<Integer> objects;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Integer> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.grid_item_layout, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = (View) i.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView i = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        t.setText("label " + position);
        i.setImageResource(objects.get(position));

        return convertView;
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, getData());
        g.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getData(){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(R.drawable.pic1);
        // add 2 - 11
        list.add(R.drawable.pic12);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Final look:

[image]

Note: From my experience when there are a lot of pictures in the gridView scrolling becomes slow and laggy, however it's not the topic of your question, so in case it's also a problem, please see [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: thanks , but can you please explain more what can i do now ,, do you mean i should replace my class with this one you put it or what ?

Comment: @lo2i updated answer, hopefully it will be understandle from the code. If not, please ask.

Comment: Spanty ,, Thank you So much it works fine with me now . but i have a question , how can i define a text for every pic ? , cuz i only can bind the picture to the list like this          `list.add(R.drawable.pic1);` << in this case i cannot bind a text to the pic Directly .

And another question how can i set a method can can get me the pressed pic ?

Best Regards

Comment: @lo2i simply create on object which will contain int resource_id and a string label; then you would extend ArrayAdapter<CustomObject> and your list would also be ArrayList<CustomObject>